# Issue opening executable module in OllyDBG

Tags: ollydbg

I am running windows 8.1 and OllyDBG 2.0. When I attach to a process and view the executable modules, I want to open one. However, when I double click on one of the modules, it won't open in the main OllyDBG window, which it should. Has anyone else had a similar issue or have a solution? I run OllyDBG as administrator and I even tried running it in compatibility mode for XP. I can provide more information if it is needed to fully answer my question.

Comment: Press `Alt`+`L` to open the Log window. What does the log say?

Comment: The log is saying: `"Different PE headers in file and in memory (System update is pending?)"`

Comment: Strangely enough though, it works just fine in OllyDBG 1.1

Comment: Most probably it is due to antivirus . Are you running Avast ? Also try to use the most recent version of ollydbg, version 2.01 released on september 2013

Comment: Well the error happens due to the fact that certain (overcautious) antivirus hook/modify the system dlls in memory and this causes a mismatch of the dll between disk and memory.

Comment: Would malwarebytes do this? How would I prevent it from interfering?

Comment: @ChrisAltig Disable the AV and see, also make sure you are running the latest version of Olly. However the best solution is to run your reversing session in a separate isolate VM. You may try VMWare.

Answer (score 1):

This has been  lying unanswered for year now
hit enter 
or right click and follow code in cpu if double clicking doesnt work

[image]